# Django & Digital Ocean: Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined") When running local server

Tags: django

I built a django app on my local machine, and then used this tutorial to deploy it with app platform (https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/) The deployment was successful.

However, now when I try to run my django app locally to continue development, I’m getting the following error:

…/settings.py", line 95, in  raise Exception(“DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined”) Exception: DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined

Current settings in settings.py: DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv(“DEVELOPMENT_MODE”, “False”) == “True”

DEBUG = os.getenv(“DEBUG”, “False”) == “True”

I am unsure of how to reset my settings.py file so that it points to a local sqlite3 db for development.

Comment: It appears that the error is being thrown here: 

```
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != 'collectstatic':
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")),
    }

```


So I beleive it's saying 'you're asking for this DEVELOPMENT_MODE environment variable, but it doesn't exist.

If yes, how do I declare environment vars for my local instance only, while keeping it hands off for the version on app platform?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't share your full settings.py file, it's difficult to say what changes you need to do.
But You can revert the *Database* and *Debug* the value to get it working in the Local Host.
The default code is given below for reference:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by overriding the DEBUG and DEVELOPMENT_MODE environment variables in the settings.py file.

```
#DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv(“DEVELOPMENT_MODE”, “False”) == “True”
DEVELOPMENT_MODE = True
```

and

```
#DEBUG = os.getenv(“DEBUG”, “False”) == “True”
DEBUG = True
```